# Constructor over methods in java

Tags: java

I want to know the exact scenario of using constructor over methods can anyone give me the exact example program for constructors over methods in java

Comment: You question does not make much sense to me.  Both are vital in some situations, and nonsense others.

Comment: When to use field initialization via a constructor rather than setter methods?

Comment: A constructor creates objects. A method either requires an existing object or (for static methods) operates independently of an object. However, you're question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: A wild guess: Are you talking about factory methods? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636243/do-we-ever-need-to-prefer-constructors-over-static-factory-methods-if-so-when

Comment: When you want to construct an object and pass in values when doing so.

Comment: Imagine you have a Calculator class with two fields, if both fields are necessary for the calculation, then it makes sense to ensure that they are set upon initialization of the  Calculator object

    Calculator calc = new Calculator (2, 5);
    int result = calc.add ();

On the other hand if you had Employee class where there were many non-mandatory fields e.g. `middleName`, then including this in the constructor would be annoying and better served by use of a setter method

     emp.setMiddleName ("Fred");

I hope this is what you were asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not similar things to compare even.

Both serves completely different purposes and even you have to note that constructor wont return anything, not even void :)

If you see a [basic tutorial on Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), mentioned

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

So you cannot choose one over them.

If you are looking/talking about setting `variables` of instance memebers, choose setter methods instead of variables.

Another scenoriao is some objects never complete without providing some basic info. In that cases you have to create a `constructor` like it should be built when necessary info passed in constructor.

Consider the below scenorio, where to create an employee class, He must have an employee Id

```
public class Employee {
    String empId;

    public Employee(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    // Methods

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee a = new Employee("green");

    }
```

Consider the below scenorio, where to create an empty employee class, later he can assign employee Id

```
public class Employee {
    private String empId;

    public Employee() {

    }

    // Methods

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee a = new Employee(); //No error
        a.setEmpId("SOMEX007");

    }
}
```

Comment: I know these but i want a scenario or a example

Comment: @Hari_krish4 Edited. Hope that helps.