# please tell me when to use getInstance() method in java.

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, blackberry

When to use the getInstance() method in java and what is the meaning of getInstance(null)?

```
locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
```

can anyone tell me the meaning of the above line?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169644/1830334) is better than the others here.

Comment: Actually, the below answer is (arguably) a lot more clear/practical than the top answer linked in the previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477281/please-tell-me-when-to-use-getinstance-method-in-java#10477301 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will give you the latitude and longitude. getInstance() will give back the instance of that particular class.

```
    Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
    myCriteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    LocationProvider myLocationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);
    Location myLocation = myLocationProvider.getLocation(300);
    latitude  = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
    longitude = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 38):

Classes that use `getInstance()` methods and the like are of the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
Basically, there will only ever be one instance of that particular class, and you get it with `getInstance()`.

In this case, `LocationProvider` will only ever have one instance, since it's device-specific. Instead of creating new instances of it, you can use the shared instance by using the `getInstance()` method. The singleton pattern is often used in Java when dealing with things like data managers and hardware interfaces, but it shouldn't be used for too much else, since it restricts you to a single instance.

Answer (score 4):

Method `getInstance()` is called factory method. It is used for singleton class creation. That means only one instance of that class will be created and others will get reference of that class.

Comment: This is incorrect. For example, `Calendar.getInstance() == Calendar.getInstance()` is `false`.

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() == Calendar.getInstance() return value depends on getInstance() implementation.

If getInstance() returns the same object each time, above equality comparison would return true