# Is Java KeyGenerator using Singleton Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Here's the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/2e317a02b5a8f9b319488ab9311521e8b4f87a0a/luni/src/main/java/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.java).

But it seems each time when the users invoke `getInstance()` it will create a new `instance`.

I should have misunderstood something.

Comment: No. It is not, and it doesn't claim to.

Comment: I think it's static factory method. This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169644/8093676.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source doesn't contradict your observation:

```
public static final KeyGenerator getInstance(String algorithm)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (algorithm == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("algorithm == null");
    }
    Engine.SpiAndProvider sap = ENGINE.getInstance(algorithm, null);
    return new KeyGenerator((KeyGeneratorSpi) sap.spi, sap.provider, algorithm);
}
```

What might be a singleton is the `SpiAndProvider` returned by `ENGINE#getInstance`. If you look further into the implementation it's not surprising that there is a new instance each time you call `getInstance` because `KeyGenerator` has instance members, initiated with the parameters you pass with a call.